# What's the best OpenLDAP VMWare appliance (VM) that you USED?

Tags: ldap, openldap

What's the best OpenLDAP VMWare appliance (VM) that you USED?

Answer (score 2):

Linux is the easiest way, and as long as it comes to Linux it does not really matter as OpenLDAP is installed more or less the same way on all the distributions.

When it comes to administration, get the Apache Directory Studio plugin for Eclipse (http://directory.apache.org/studio/downloads.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a preinstalled appliance, have you tried searching the [VMware Appliance catalog](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/cat/0?k=openldap&c=0)? There are descriptions and ratings for some of them.

If you are building your own, I'd suggest you go with Debian or CentOS (or Ubuntu or Fedora if you want more up to date software), depending on which one you are more comfortable with, as those are big distributions and give you easy security updates.